# Why is traversing more time-consuming than merging on two sorted std::list?

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, traversal

I am pretty amazed on the result that traversing takes more time than merging on two sorted `std::list` by around 12%. Since merging can be considered and implemented as continuous element comparisons, list splice and iterators traversal through two separated sorted linked lists. Hence, traversing should not be slower than merging through them especially when two lists are large enough because the ratio of iterated elements is getting increased.

However, the result seems to not match what I thought, and this is how I test my ideas above:

```
std::list<int> list1, list2;

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1 << 22; cnt++)
    list1.push_back(rand());
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1 << 23; cnt++)
    list2.push_back(rand());

list1.sort();
list2.sort();

auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  // C++ wall clock

// Choose either one option below
list1.merge(list2);         // Option 1
for (auto num : list1);     // Option 2
for (auto num : list2);     // Option 2

std::chrono::duration<double> diff = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << "\n       "
          << diff.count() << " seconds (measured)" << std::endl;  // show elapsed time
```

PS. `icc` is smart enough to eliminate Option 2. Try `sum += num;` and print out `sum`.

This is the output from `perf`: (the measured time remains the same without using `perf`)

Option 1: Merge

```
       0.904575206 seconds (measured)

 Performance counter stats for './option-1-merge':

    33,395,981,671      cpu-cycles
       149,371,004      cache-misses              #   49.807 % of all cacherefs
       299,898,436      cache-references
    24,254,303,068      cycle-activity.stalls-ldm-pending    

       7.678166480 seconds time elapsed
```

Option 2: Traverse

```
       1.01401903 seconds (measured)

 Performance counter stats for './option-2-traverse':

    33,844,645,296      cpu-cycles
       138,723,898      cache-misses             #   48.714 % of all cacherefs
       284,770,796      cache-references
    25,141,751,107      cycle-activity.stalls-ldm-pending

       7.806018949 seconds time elapsed
```

Due to the property of horrible spatial locality on these linked lists. The cache miss is the major reason that make CPU stalls, and occupies most of the CPU resources. The strange point is that option 2 has fewer cache misses than option 1, but it has a higher amount of CPU stalls and CPU cycles to accomplish its task. What makes this abnormality happen?

Comment: Can you paste the _exact_ code you used to benchmark? BTW use `std::steady_clock` or `std::high_resolution_clock` for measurements

Comment: @PasserBy This is the exact code. The remaining parts are including headers and `int main(void) {}`. I have tried Linux `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` and `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and got the same results.

Comment: I would guess the merge algorithm doesn't require creating and using an iterator to do the merge but rather directly access the underlying data structure. Just my guess though.

Comment: Oh FFS, people are actually using that `-->` abomination?

Comment: @apokryfos [This](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a00925_source.html#l00285) is how GCC implements. Iterators are needed.

Comment: @hvd It does increase code readability. ;-)

Comment: @KevinDong it wouldn't survive any professional code review. for a reason.

Comment: @KevinDong It does the exact opposite of improve readability.

Comment: @Miles Okay, I changed the code.

Comment: @KevinDong Moving the whitespace isn't how you make it more readable.  Putting the increment in the place designed for it is how you make it readable.

Comment: And the canonic answer to such questions is: compare the generated assembly code. Maybe it proves @apokryfos theory

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think I was proven wrong at least in GCC.

Comment: Since your program needs time to execute unused loops, I would assume, that you didn't enable the optimizer.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/092dbc8ec87c73f6). Please post the __full__ code and the compile options for such questions.

Comment: @PasserBy You didn't enable optimisation. Edit the command line, add `-O3`, and see a different result.

Comment: @manni66 Reasonable guess, but GCC's optimiser doesn't manage to eliminate it.

Comment: @manni66 I have tested this on gcc 6.3.0, llvm 3.8.0, and icc 17.0.4 on Ubuntu. All of them yield the same result: Option 2 is slower than Option 1 when `-O3` and `-flto` are enabled.

Comment: @hvd With that, runtime of traversal loops should be exactly zero... However, I agree that you need to switch on optimizations to get sensible benchmark results - optimizing away of the benchmarked part must be stopped by actually using results. A simple `int sum = 0; for (num : list1) sum += num; /*stop time*/; cout << sum;` will suffice.

Comment: @cmaster "With that, runtime of traversal loops should be exactly zero..." -- If that did give zero, I would agree, something like that would be the way to prevent optimising it away, but it doesn't give zero in the first place, the loop is kept. I think it's because the optimiser can't rule out cycles in a linked list, and goes through the effort to ensure the infinite loop is kept for that impossible case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, it is memory that is taking all your time.

Cache misses are bad, but so are stalls.

From [this paper](http://www.readex.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ICPE2017_authors_version.pdf):

> Applications with irregular memory access patterns, e.g.,dereferencing chains of pointers when traversing linked lists or trees, may not generate enough concurrently outstanding requests to fully utilize the data paths. Nevertheless, such applications are clearly limited by the performance of memory accesses as well. Therefore, considering the bandwidth utilization is not sufficient to detect all memory related performance issues.

Basically, randomly walking pointers can fail to saturate the memory bandwidth.

The tight loop on each is blocked each iteration by waiting on where the next pointer is to be loaded.  If it is not in cache, the cpu can do nothing -- it stalls.

The combined tight loop/merge tries to load *two* pages into the cache.  When one is loading, *sometimes* the cpu can advannce on the other.

The result you measured was that the merge has fewer stalls that the naked wasted double iteration.

Or in other words,

> ```
> 24,254,303,068      cycle-activity.stalls-ldm-pending
> ```

is a big number and smaller than:

> ```
> 25,141,751,107      cycle-activity.stalls-ldm-pending
> ```

I am surprised this is enough to make a 10% difference, but that is why perf is about measuring.

Comment: This predicts that if range of values from the first list does not intersect the range of values in the second list, e.g: `for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1 << 22; cnt++) list1.push_back(rand() / 2); for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1 << 23; cnt++) list2.push_back(RAND_MAX / 2 + rand() / 2);` then merge would have to to iterate entire `list1` and then entire `list2`, with no concurrent loads, same as simple iteration. And would be at least as slow, but this does not appear to o be the case.